# Cannot set Android minSDK to 7 with Cordova 5.0.0

Tags: android, cordova

I have installed cordova 5.0.0. I am trying to set the minSDK to 7 so I can run my project on a 2.3 Android device but it doesn't work.

What I've tried:

1) Running "cordova -d run android --minSdkVersion=7"

2) Edit the projectname/config.xml and add,

```
 <platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="7" />
 </platform>
```

3) Edit the AndroidManifest.xml in platforms/android/CordovaLib and change uses-sdk to "7"

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
```

Nothing of the above works, the error I am getting is that the minSDK can be as low as 14.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Cordova supports Android 4.0.x (starting with Android API level 14)
>   and higher. As a general rule, Android versions become unsupported by
>   Cordova as they dip below 5% on Google's distribution dashboard.
>   Android versions earlier than API level 10, and the 3.x versions
>   (Honeycomb, API levels 11-13) fall significantly below that 5%
>   threshold.

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0/guide/platforms/android/index.html

To run Cordova on Android 2.3 try [Cordova 4](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide/platforms/android/index.html).

Comment: Ah that's a bummer but alright, thanks. I managed to run the app on the device with Cordova 4.0.0